# GWT: how to attach GAE Blob data to new PDF file

Tags: google-app-engine, pdf, gwt, blob

I have a PDF file stored in GAE server and I want to display it on the client side. How can I make the new pdf file? I try do this:

```
String str = toBase64(result.get(1));// result.get(1) has byte[] type
HeadElement headElement = Document.get().createHeadElement();
LinkElement link = Document.get().createLinkElement();
link.setType("application/pdf");
link.setHref("Content-Disposition\", \"attachment;filename=" +  str);
headElement.appendChild(link);
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do it on the client. On the client, you simply show a link like

```
https://myapp.com/file?id=123
```

if you store blobs by ids, or you can use a blob key, etc. On the server side, you need a servlet `/file` which will take this id or key, retrieve the blob, and set the correct headers on the response:

```
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + "somename.pdf");
response.setContentType("application/pdf");
OutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream();
// document is byte[]
outputStream.write(document);
outputStream.close();
```

Then a browser would know that the incoming response is a PDF file. So it will ask a user where to save it.